# How to handle list loading + errors on mobile

Tags: mobile, error-message, pagination, loading

I have a list of addresses on a mobile app.  What is the best way to handle pagination and loading errors?

example:

- The list is paginated by default.  5 items are shown, with a "Load more" button
- what happens if user presses "Load more" and there is a server error?
- should I maintain the 5 items that have already loaded and show a modal error?
- should I show an empty state with error message instead of the whole list?
- should I maintain the 5 items and show an error state below the items?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some more detail for the use case: How many addresses fit onto a regular screen? Is the list sorted somehow, and how likely is it that the selected address is on the first page? Is there a sorting/filtering mechanism, and what to users sort/filter? As you can see on the internet, and in your list of questions, there are many different solutions. Some of them are simply better than others, but many of them are just more appropriate to the respective use case. As long as you are not clear on your use case, you might as well just pick any of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In the context you've described, specifically when the user clicks "load more" and the initial 5 items have already loaded, it's crucial to address the server error appropriately. Typically, server errors prevent the display of regular content, resulting in a blank screen accompanied by the server-generated error message.

Distinctions exist between errors originating from the application code base and those stemming from server issues. The behaviours of these two types of errors differ significantly.

If the "load more" action triggers a server error, my recommendation is to implement the following approach: "Display an empty state with an error message instead of presenting the entire list." On the other hand, if the error is not associated with the server but rather with the application itself, you should consider this alternative: "Maintain the display of the initial 5 items and showcase an error state below them."

I think this approach provides the users with clear and relevant feedback, ensuring a more user-friendly experience in response to different error scenarios.